# How do I change the unstable build email subject and how to include the environment name in the subject line of the email?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I am not able to change the subject of the email notification of jenkins for unstable build. I also have to include the environment name in the subject line of the email which we are receiving.

I tried installing the extended email notification plugin but its also not working and I can see failure msg on the console for editable notification. I receive email only for unstable build.

Comment: Please help to add your Jenkinsfile (what you have tried) and also add the error in the description to understand the question better.